# Adding service reference for oData 4 Web api to VS Web Developer Express

Tags: c#, web-services, odata

Wondering if anyone knows of a way to **add a service reference** to Visual Web Developer 2013 **Express version** for a **Web API** using the **new oData 4** controllers.

I did see a post about the **odata 4 client generation tool** being released on the Visual Studio gallery, but **only works with the full version** of Visual Studio!

Trying to avoid having to pay for a solution whilst testing the functionality, to see if it's worth upgrading from WCF.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding service reference for OData v4 is supported for now in visual studio.

But you can use code generation for OData v4 service.

Check this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply, but again, this requires full version of Visual Studio to use the code generation tool. Looking for a solution with Express versions.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is a way to consuming an OData service? You may try http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/ OData Client for .NET.